# res.locals passed to ejs gives error undefiend in deployment

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, ejs

I made a middleware to save req.user coming from passport, into a variable currentUser in res.locals.
the app works fine in my local host,
but when I deploy I get currentUser is not defined in the ejs template, and I think this is also the case for all other variables passed using res.render to the ejs templates.

I'm deploying in [Render.com](https://render.com/)

screenshots: [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJO0D.jpg)
github:  [github](https://github.com/SaifAshrafHelmy/campRanger)

I tried various deployment platform, and failed to deploy on any of them.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)